# Counting 2 Columns as 1 in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, reporting

I am attempting to select a count of rows for grouped by 2 columns. For instance, in the following table, I need to return 3 for Brenda, and 2 for Jim.

| bookingid | bookingrep2 | sales_assist |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Brenda |  |
| 2 | Brenda |  |
| 3 | Jim | Brenda |
| 4 | Jim |  |

If the persons name is in either bookingrep2 or sales_assist columns, they are counted. I was thinking this would be a union, but in this case the count is doubled.

query edited for clarity...

```
SELECT        bookingid, sales_assist AS Regional_Rep
FROM            bookings
UNION ALL
SELECT bookingid, bookingRep2 AS Regional_Rep
FROM            bookings
```

Comment: Make it easy to assist you, simplify! [mcve]

Comment: Union, aggregate and count. Is the behemoth of a query you've dumped in your question  relevant to the table of data? What are you expecting for an answer?

Comment: Please read [this](https://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/) for some tips on improving your question. Posting a query that appears to be tangentially related to your question doesn't help us help you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Option 1: **unpivot**

```
select   u.person
        ,count(*) as cnt
from     bookings as b unpivot (person for col in (bookingrep2, sales_assist)) as u
group by u.person
```

---

Option 2: **cross apply + values**

```
select   ca.person
        ,count(*) as cnt
from     bookings as b cross apply (values (bookingrep2), (sales_assist)) as ca (person)
where    ca.person is not null
group by ca.person
```

---

```
+--------+-----+
| person | cnt |
+--------+-----+
| Brenda |   3 |
| Jim    |   2 |
+--------+-----+
```

[Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=9dcebaa6e2f6c3d59d896c43de3520d5)

Answer (score 0):

You probably have the Person's (maybe `Employee` table) central table I am guessing, if yes, then you can `inner join` on that table using these 2 fields and then do a `group` on the ID/Name.

```
declare @booking table(BookingID int not null identity, BookingRep2 varchar(100), SalesAssist varchar(100));

insert into @booking(BookingRep2, SalesAssist)
    values ('Brenda', null)
        , ('Brenda', null)
        , ('Jim', 'Brenda')
        , ('Jim', null)

declare @person table(Person varchar(100));

insert into @person(Person)
    values ('Brenda')
            , ('Jim')
            , ('John')

select  p.Person, count(1) as TotalTimes
from    @booking as b
        inner join @person as p on b.BookingRep2 = p.Person
                                        or b.SalesAssist = p.Person
group by p.Person

-- Output:
--    Person  |  TotalTimes
--    --------|------------
--    Brenda  |  3
--    Jim     |  2
```